# Why is `str_extract` only catching some of these values?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a table that has a "membership type" column that includes a zillion different membership levels that we've used over the years.

```
example <-data.frame(membership = c( "Legacy Payment ID #3564, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N", 
                              "Legacy Payment ID #3611, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 2 Flag: N", 
                              "Legacy Payment ID #4105, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: G",
                              "Legacy Payment ID #4136, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N", 
                              "Legacy Payment ID #5191, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N ", 
                              "Individual (2 yr)",
                              "Individual Producer (Yearly)",
                              "Student Membership (Yearly)"  ))
```

I would expect that I could add a second column, with at least a rough set of possible values for the membership term with `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
example$term <-  example$membership %>% 
  str_extract(c("Period Paid: 1","Period Paid: 2","Yearly", "2 yr"))
```

But that's only catching half the values and I can't find a pattern in what it is skipping.

```
1   Legacy Payment ID #3564, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  Period Paid: 1
2   Legacy Payment ID #3611, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 2 Flag: N  Period Paid: 2
3   Legacy Payment ID #4105, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: G  NA
4   Legacy Payment ID #4136, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  NA
5   Legacy Payment ID #5191, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  Period Paid: 1
6   Legacy Payment ID #5238, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  NA
7   Legacy Payment ID #5287, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  NA
8   Legacy Payment ID #5306, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  NA
9   Legacy Payment ID #5739, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 2 Flag: G  NA
10  Individual (2 yr)                                                   NA
11  Individual Producer (Yearly)                                        Yearly
12  Student Membership (Yearly)                                         NA
```

The only difference between row 4 and row 5 is the Payment ID. Why is it only finding the search value in Row 5?

And how do I fix it. But mostly why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can collapse it to a single string with `|`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
pattern_vec <- c("Period Paid: 1","Period Paid: 2","Yearly", "2 yr")
example%>% 
      mutate(term = str_extract(membership,
      str_c(pattern_vec, collapse="|")))
#                                                       membership           term
#1  Legacy Payment ID #3564, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N Period Paid: 1
#2  Legacy Payment ID #3611, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 2 Flag: N Period Paid: 2
#3  Legacy Payment ID #4105, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: G Period Paid: 1
#4  Legacy Payment ID #4136, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N Period Paid: 1
#5 Legacy Payment ID #5191, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  Period Paid: 1
#6                                                   Individual (2 yr)           2 yr
#7                                        Individual Producer (Yearly)         Yearly
#8                                         Student Membership (Yearly)         Yearly
```

---

`str_extract` is vectorized for both the 'string' and 'pattern' except that if there is a vector of length > 1 in 'pattern', then it would be doing an elementwise match i.e. 1st value of 'membership' to 1st value of pattern, 2nd to 2nd and so on.  Here, in the OP's case, the lengths are different i.e. column length is different than the pattern length.  So, the pattern vector does a recycling by repeating itself from the start after row 4.

In order to check the recycling, you can use `rep` to replicate the `pattern_vec` and check the output:

```
out1 <- example %>% 
      mutate(term = str_extract(membership, rep(pattern_vec, length.out = n())))

out2 <- example %>% 
            mutate(term = str_extract(membership,  pattern_vec))
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE



out1
#                                                           membership           term
#1  Legacy Payment ID #3564, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N Period Paid: 1
#2  Legacy Payment ID #3611, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 2 Flag: N Period Paid: 2
#3  Legacy Payment ID #4105, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: G           <NA>
#4  Legacy Payment ID #4136, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N           <NA>
#5 Legacy Payment ID #5191, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  Period Paid: 1
#6                                                   Individual (2 yr)           <NA>
#7                                        Individual Producer (Yearly)         Yearly
#8                                         Student Membership (Yearly)           <NA>
```

*Note from OP:*

A post on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/understanding-the-use-of-str-replace-all-with-multiple-patterns/1849) that helped me (OP) understand the explanation above:

> When fed with a single pattern, `str_replace_all` will compare that pattern for against every element. However, if you pass it a vector, it will try to respect the order, so compare the first pattern with the first object, then the second pattern with the second object.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this would work and the example doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a more complex regex, using lookbehind and lookahead:

```
example$term <-  example$membership %>% 
    str_extract("Period Paid: \\d+|(?<=\\().*(?=\\))")
```

Output:

```
example
                                                           membership           term
1  Legacy Payment ID #3564, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N Period Paid: 1
2  Legacy Payment ID #3611, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 2 Flag: N Period Paid: 2
3  Legacy Payment ID #4105, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: G Period Paid: 1
4  Legacy Payment ID #4136, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N Period Paid: 1
5 Legacy Payment ID #5191, Payment Record #0, Period Paid: 1 Flag: N  Period Paid: 1
6                                                   Individual (2 yr)           2 yr
7                                        Individual Producer (Yearly)         Yearly
8                                         Student Membership (Yearly)         Yearly
```

Comment: Definitely a more elegant solution, but ... why would the first version only match some results?

Comment: My hunch is--but really just a hunch-- that it's because the first version is a concatenation of as many as four distinct literal matches whereas my regex is for a single (despite the `|`), compact, and abstract match.

Comment: My hunch that it's the singleness that does the trick is supported by the fact that @akrun's solution, which also matches exhaustively, also collapses the four distinct patterns into a single one.

Comment: I've done a number of test trials and I'm pretty sure now that it's the concatenation that doesn't work well. For example, `example$test <-  example$membership %>% 
  str_extract(c("ID #3", "ID #4", "ID #5"))`throws an error, whereas this works perfectly:
`example$test <-  example$membership %>% 
  str_extract("ID #[3-5]")`

Comment: Added a note to @akrun's solution, from a RStudio Community post. https://community.rstudio.com/t/understanding-the-use-of-str-replace-all-with-multiple-patterns/1849 -- explains how the matching works.

Comment: Fully confirms my suspicion that it's the concatenation that causes the imperfect matching.